# How many strawberry plants can you plant in a 10" hanging basket?

Tags: container-gardening, strawberries

I have a couple of extra plastic 10" hanging baskets and soil and I'd like to plant some more strawberries. Likely some sort of everbearing variety like Evie that I'll get as bare root plants.

How many plants can I add in each 10" planter without making holes on the sides of the planter? I may do that too but not sure if I want to bother with that yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you COULD put as many as you like, but I suspect one is all that's worth planting in that small of a pot. The root mass on an established plant is at least as big as one of those hanging basket pots, IME.

3 seems a likely practical limit, but I'm dubious that you'll get any more fruit from 3 crammed in than one with the whole pot.

Comment: Agreed, and one can spread too, in case there is enough room. I'd go with 3-4 though if they were alpine.

Comment: This comment is also for @J.Musser too. I was under the impression that strawberries had shallow root systems. That's why you could cram a bunch of them in those tiered planters, gutter planters, vertical pipe planters and I've seen people stick them all around and on top of those coir hanging baskets. Is that not a good way to go? If I cut out some holes on the sides of the planter can I fit more than 3? The minimum you can order online is 10 plants so I'm trying to figure out how to plant all of them because I don't have anywhere else for them to go.

Comment: The root system is not the (only) problem. If the plants are too close together, they will steal away sunlight from each others leaves and fruits. That's why in those vertical pipe planters, you can fit a large number. That also means that if you make holes in the side, you may as well fit 5 or 6 plants in the basket (also depending on the height of the basket).

Comment: Any chance you can provide some general guidance for spacing, soil depth, soil volume or similar?

Comment: My main issue was I didn't think I had enough soil left. I wound up ordering 3 Temptation Strawberries and when I was filling pots I realized I had enough potting mix left for 3 baskets so I'll be putting each one in  it's own pot. Unless these varieties can fit more in one basket. Checked spacing and it's 12" so it looks like 1 per pot would be best.